# Is there a way to count messages by an user using discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm new to coding, so I might have missed something, but I was wondering if there is a way to get the amount of messages a user has sent in the server. I know I can do a JSON database, but that wouldn't be that useful since the bot won't count the messages sent before the database was made. I was thinking about something like the magnifying glass for normal users, but for a bot. Is there any way to do it? Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately, Discord doesn't provide an API for that.

Comment: Just for the novelty, this is probably possible with web scraping.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this is to fetch all the messages sent in all the text channels of a server, and then count how many are from a user. However, this would be very slow.